# Extract image form a div and insert it into another div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html

```
<Div id=Qimage>
<a href="http.wwww.....somehitng">
<img class="postphoto" src="">
</a>
</div>

<Div id=Limage>
<a href="www.designerzblog.com" imageanchor="1" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="/feather/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/06.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**I need to move ONLY image from #Limage and insert it in the src of #Qimage.
After insert the #Limage should be invisible.**

How can do this in simple javascript??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#Qimage img').attr('src', $('#Limage img').attr('src'));
```

Comment: will this script make the #limage invisible after the movement

Comment: Above script only set the `src` of your image, it cannot affect the visibility of your `div`.